# App finds driver without hbm.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

How can it be that when I delete the hbm.cfg.xml file the app anyhow finds the driver at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test. I changed the database name in my standalone.xml... but from there it isn't. Does anyone know how the driver is being found without hbm.cfg.xml and a changed standalone.xml?

Comment: might want to tag it as hibernate as well?  And assuming that you restarted the program/server after making these changes

Comment: shurte i did restart it

Comment: add some code to show how your loading your cfg.xml. are you using spring?

Comment: _finds the driver at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_ There is no Driver there, that's the address of your database. The driver, if you're using jdbc 4, will be loaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat, make sure you delete the webapp/{webappname} directory if you are deploying a new .war file or the exploded directory might get used and not your new .war archive, hope that helps...